# Multiple choice question about an entire function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ and the function $g :\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C} $ defined by $ g(z)= f(z) - f(z+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C} $ be an entire function and let $g : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ be defined by 
$$g(z)= f(z) - f(z+1)$$ for all $ z\in \mathbb{C}$. Which of the options are correct :

1. if $ f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0 $ for all positive integers n, then $f$ is a constant function.
2. if $ f(n) = 0 $ for all positive integers n, then $f$ is a constant function.
3. if $ f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(\frac{1}{n}+1)$ for all positive integers n, then $g$ is a constant function.
4. $ f(n) = f(n+1) $  for all positive integers $n$, then $g$ is a constant function

Please suggest which of the options are correct.

Using the Identity theorem, the options 1 and 3 seem to be correct as in both cases, the sequence of zeros for $\,f\,$ and $\,g\,$  is $ < \frac{1}{n} >$ that converges to zero which belongs to $\Bbb C$. Therefore, in both cases $\,f\,$ and $\,g\,$ are identically equal to zero.  But in (2) and (4), we arrive for both $\,f\,$ and $\,g\,$, at the zeros sequence $ <{n}>$ diverges to infinity which does not ensure the required conclusion.

Comment: 2. false: let $f(x)=sin(\pi x)$ for example.

Comment: Note the $g(z)$ is also entire. Hence, if we specify the value of $g(z)$ on a convergent sequence then $g$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity theorem for analytic functions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: 1.true: the set of zeros of $f$ has a accumulation point in $0$

Comment: @Potato: Thanks, I used it and it seems that according to that options 1 and 3 seem to be correct. But the book says all options are correct.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @preeti : ( out of math question ) which competitive exam ?

Comment: 4. false: Let again $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is a compilation of the answers given in the comments above.

To answer these questions, you should be familiar with the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

**1.** True. The set of zeros of $f(z)$ has an accumulation point at $0$, so $f$ is identically zero.

**2.** False. Consider $f(z)=\sin(\pi  z)$.

**3.** True. We have $f(1/n)=f(1/n+1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $g(1/n)=f(1/n)-f(1+1/n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and the set of zeros has an accumulation point at 0, so $g$ is identically zero.

**4.** False. Again, consider $f(z)=\sin(\pi  z)$.